# Name of the linkage (or carriage) in video

Tags: mechanism, robotic-arm, identification

I am trying to find the name (nomenclature) of the linkage (or carriage) that is being driven by the dual linear servo (actuator) arrangement in the following Youtube videos:

- [Servo Basic Concepts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Le9hyRdcnOg)
- [YouTube - 4 X Linear Servo Application](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P1kTsvfH2ss)

The linkage (carriage) appears to be able to rotate about a 180 degree arc.

What is this metal linkage (or carriage) system called?

Answer (score 4):

The video shows 2 linear actuators driving a [universal joint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_joint) through [ball and socket joints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_joint).